# Which of the following are not class equations?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Which of the following are not class equations of a group of order 10?

A) 1+1+1+2+5=10

B) 1+2+3+4=10

C) 1+2++2+5=10

D) 1+1+2+2+2+2=10

So obviously $1+1+1+2+5$ is not a class equation because in this equation the order of the center of $G$ is 3 which does not divide 10.

$1+2+3+4$ is also not because 3 is not a factor of 10

I am trying to apply Sylows results and show that the other two are also not. I need help.

Comment: [C] is the only one which may be a class equation of a group of order 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171656/number-of-non-isomorphic-non-abelian-groups-of-order-10) for instance, one can prove that $D_{10}$ is the only nonabelian group of order 10. Thus all you need to do is compute its class equation.