# Non-isomorphic non-abelian groups of order 243?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm trying to exhibit two non-isomorphic non-abelian groups of order $243 = 3^5$.

I know that there are subgroups of order $3^k$ for $k$ ranging from $0$ to $5$ inclusive, where the subgroup of order $3$ is cyclic, but unsure how to proceed: I was also taking a look at a [similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171656/number-of-non-isomorphic-non-abelian-groups-of-order-10) but feel like I might be missing something.

Any hints are appreciated; I was just interested since it's a practice prelim question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** For any prime $p$ [there are (exactly) two nonabelian groups of order $p^3$ up to isomorphism](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_groups_of_prime-cube_order).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to guess what you would expected to know at a prelim (may be you're in a program with more ivy than mine had, but anyway). Undoubtedly you have done the exercise of showing that matrices over $\Bbb{F}_3$ with the shape
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&*&*\\0&1&*\\0&0&1\end{array}\right)
$$
form a non-abelian group of order $3^3$ (the exercise often requiring you to check that all the non-identity matrices are of order $3$)

Why don't you try shapes
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}1&0&0&*&*\\0&1&0&0&*\\0&0&1&0&*\\
0&0&0&1&*\\0&0&0&0&1\end{array}\right)
$$
and
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}1&0&*&*\\0&1&*&*\\0&0&1&*\\
0&0&0&1\end{array}\right)?
$$